# Does yslow supports iframes?

Tags: javascript, performance, yslow

Does yslow works on iframes? ON official website its written that it loops through all frames. But its not working for me. Can anybody suggest me if I need to change any settings? I am using Yslow on chrome.

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue (ref: [Github](https://github.com/marcelduran/yslow/issues/109)) with the Chrome YSlow extension that it does not support iframes.

Alternative you could try until that is fixed:

- [YSlow Firefox extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5369)
- [YSlow bookmarklet](http://developer.yahoo.com/yslow/mobile) in Chrome

I just tried both of the above on an [iframe test page](http://scooterlabs.com/yslow/iframe.html) I made and YSlow correctly flowed through the iframee.